# How to shorten Formula in formula field to stay with character limitations?

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have the following formula in my formula field that assigns a value to Contact that meet the listed criteria. However, I am not able to save the field as I get the following error:
"Error: Compiled formula is too big to execute (10,999 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters " Is there any way to get around this?

This is the formula:

```
CASE(
    IF(
        OR(
            TEXT(Status__c) = "Current",
            TEXT(Status__c) = "Ongoing",
            TEXT(Status__c) = "Lapsed"
        ),
        "S",
        "X"
    ) +

    IF(
        TEXT(Practitioner_Group__c) = "Consultant",
        "C",
        "X"
    ) +

    IF(
        MailingCity = "London",
        "L",
        "X"
    ) +

    CASE(
        Practitioner_Speciality__c,
        "Orthopaedic",      "A",
        "Neurosurgery",     "B",
        "Neurology",        "C",
        "Rheumatology",     "D",
        "ENT",              "E",
        "Sports Medicine",  "F",
        "Pain Medicine",    "G",
        "X"
    ),

    /*Valid Status(S), Consultant(C), London(L) and one of the valid specialities(A-G).*/
    "SCLA", "3",
    "SCLB", "3",
    "SCLC", "2",
    "SCLD", "2",
    "SCLE", "2",
    "SCLF", "2",
    "SCLG", "2",

    /*Valid Status(S), Consultant(C), London(L) and no speciality(X)*/
    "SCLX", "1",

    /*Valid Status(S), Consultant(C), not from London(X) and one of the valid speciality(A-G.*/
    "SCXA", "2",
    "SCXB", "2",
    "SCXC", "2",
    "SCXD", "1",
    "SCXE", "1",
    "SCXF", "1",
    "SCXG", "1",

    NULL
)
```

Updated formula:

Case(

```
  IF(

    2 > CASE(
    Clinician_Status__c, "Current", 1, "Ongoing", 1, "Lapsed", 1, 0
    ) + IF(ISPICKVAL(Practitioner_Group__c, "Consultant"), 1, 0,NULL)
     )

   IF(
   MailingCity = "London",
   CASE(
       Practitioner_Speciality__c,
       "Orthopaedic", "3",
       "Neurosurgery", "3",
       "Neurology", "2",
       "Rheumatology", "2",
       "ENT", "2",
       "Sports Medicine", "2",
       "Pain Medicine", "2",
       1
        ),
    CASE(
         Practitioner_Speciality__c,
         "Orthopaedic", "2",
         "Neurosurgery", "2",
         "Neurology", "2",
         "Rheumatology", "1",
         "ENT", "1",
         "Sports Medicine", "1",
         "Pain Medicine", "1",
         NULL
         )
    )
```

)

Comment: This [documentation](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_formula_size_tipsheet.pdf) about how to reduce formulas might help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most obvious change off the bat is to collapse your section of the formula using multiple `ISPICKVAL`/`TEXT` calls.

**Instead of:**

```
IF(
    OR(
        TEXT(Status__c) = "Current",
        TEXT(Status__c) = "Ongoing",
        TEXT(Status__c) = "Lapsed"
    ),
    "S",
    "X"
)
```

**Use:**

```
CASE(
    Status__c,
    "Current", "S", "Ongoing", "S", "Lapsed", "S",
    "X"
)
```

---

Since your formula is always null if that initial concatenation evaluates to anything other than `"SC"`, you can also just check your `"SC"` conditions once, and if either is false to short circuit the whole evaluation.

```
IF(
    2 > CASE(
        Status__c, "Current", 1, "Ongoing", 1, "Lapsed", 1, 0
    ) + IF(ISPICKVAL(Practitioner_Group__c, "Consultant", 1, 0),
    NULL,
    /*check the last two conditions here*/
)
```

Now that falsy condition can be simplified somewhat:

```
IF(
    BillingCity = "London",
    CASE(
        Practitioner_Speciality__c,
        "Orthopaedic", "3",
        "Neurosurgery", "3",
        "Neurology", "2",
        "Rheumatology", "2",
        "ENT", "2",
        "Sports Medicine", "2",
        "Pain Medicine", "2",
        1
    ),
    CASE(
        Practitioner_Speciality__c,
        "Orthopaedic", "2",
        "Neurosurgery", "2",
        "Neurology", "2",
        "Rheumatology", "1",
        "ENT", "1",
        "Sports Medicine", "1",
        "Pain Medicine", "1",
        NULL
    )
)
```

Comment: @Sophie let's continue this conversation in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69379/discussion-on-answer-by-adrian-larson-how-to-shorten-formula-in-formula-field-to).

Answer (score 0):

Counting your characters I got something about 1182. Doesn't look that bad.
But as described here: [Tips for Reducing Formula Size](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_formula_size_tipsheet.pdf), other formulas used in your formula also count into your limit. I would suggest reading the whole document to come up with a more efficient way of writing your formulas.

So in your case if `Status__c` is a formula field, it is counted 3 times into your limit. Meaning that if it has abou 3000 characters 9000 characters are counted into this formula. `Practitioner_Group__c` and `Practitioner_Speciality__c` are counted once (in case they are formulas).

Comment: Thank you for the document; the issue is that I am not referencing any other formula fields in this formula, and it is still giving me that error.